# Read Biopax file in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can we read ***Biopax*** file in ***matlab***, ***biopax*** is special type of ***xml*** file. How we can retrieve information from it using ***matlab***.

Answer (score 0):

There is a BioConductor package for reading and manipulating BioPAX files in R (http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/paxtoolsr.html).

Check out the related tutorial on getting set up in R:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWSbcyynroIp-f6O3sfz7jg

AND using PaxtoolsR:
http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/paxtoolsr/inst/doc/using_paxtoolsr.html